# InboxState.Delivered = null - Transactional Outbox For Consumers

Tags: masstransit

A consumer with `EF Core` transactional outbox configured never sets the `Delivered` field in the `InboxState` table when it throws an Exception.

Therefore those 'undelivered' messages will never be deleted by the [cleanup service](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/0341a02e74f93b54d0f8c6a70616b969d76af964/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/InboxCleanupService.cs#L105).

- Is this the desired behavior and shouldn't also those messages be deleted after the `DuplicateDetectionWindow`?
- If it is the desired behavior, how to handle this scenario without flooding the database when consumer exceptions happen?

Comment: All messages should eventually be delivered to the broker. If they aren't, it sounds like you didn't properly configure retry/redelivery for the receive endpoint.

Comment: I am new to Mass transit and just exploring. I am using RabbitMQ as transport. I configured retries but in this scenario I was just hardcoded always throwing an exception. Adding redelivery makes sense but maybe even that could end in consumer exceptions. What I was wondering and my confusion comes from is that technically my message has been moved to the _error queue. Shouldn't that count as delivered?